# Save SVG with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, svg, phantomjs

I have a sample testpage with an SVG tag that I am trying to save as an SVG file with PhantomJS. I can use PhantomJS to get to the testpage but then I can't figure out how to find and save the svg. Here is how I tried to do it and where I got stuck.

1. Nagivate to webpage
2. Try to find svg tag with document.getElementsByTagName('svg')
3. What to do from here? I can see phantom returns a huge object but can't find anything on their website on what to do with this. How do I convert this object into an svg file?

The testpage looks like this:

```
<HTML>

This is a Testpage. You like it, don't you?

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myLinearGradient1"
                    x1="0%" y1="0%"
                    x2="0%" y2="100%"
                    spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#00cc00" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#006600" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="75" height="100" rx="10" ry="10"
     style="fill:url(#myLinearGradient1);
            stroke: #005000;
            stroke-width: 3;" />

</svg>

</HTML>
```

and the PhantomJS script

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);

function getSVG(link, callback) {
    page.open(link, function(status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to access network');
        } else {
            var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
            });
            // Don't know what to do here
        }
        phantom.exit();
        callback();
    });
}

getSVG('testpage', function () {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var svg = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector("svg").outerHTML;
});

var fs = require("fs");
fs.write("file.svg", svg);
```

should get you started, but this might not be enough, because SVG can be manipulated with CSS.